# Para no ser una IP SPAM

Tags: python, django

Mi problema es que mi sistema ya no envía los emails de validación de cuenta para los usuarios que se registran en la aplicación web.

Me dijeron que hay una forma de validar que son usuarios de mi base de datos y que ellos quieren recibir esos emails, y así no marcan como spam la IP del servidor.

Estamos usando Python/Django... 
¿Dónde podría leer sobre este tema o cómo podría buscar información?

Gracias!!

Comment: primero verifica que empresas te consideran spam https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: En cuanto a que no te consideren spam (si no hacés spam claro) tenes que autorizar al servidor de correo a enviar emails de tu dominio. Lo que tenes que buscar es: SPF y DKIM. Lo otro que preguntas no lo entandí.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de como esta configurado el correo en django

Comment: Gracias!! Voy a buscar y revisar lo que me han comentado! :D